# Who is listening on my 80 port

Tags: windows-7, port, telnet

In My PC, I am running :

```
telnet localhost 80
```

and it seems that there is an answer.
No IIS runs, no java server runs.

How do I know which process listens to 80 port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open command prompt as administrator and run the below command

```
C:\>netstat -a -b
```

`netstat` is used to display information and statistics about the network connections. The flag `-a` makes it display all connections and listening ports and the flag `-b` makes it show the associated executable.